# Prove that, in a graph with $200$ vertices and $200$ edges, there is a subset of $67$ vertices in which no two vertices are connected by an edge

Tags: graph-theory

> A graph has $200$ vertices and $200$ edges. Prove that there is a subset of $67$ vertices in which no two vertices are connected by an edge.

From Intuition I tried the following:

200 vertices can have $\frac{200(200-1)}{2}$ edges which mean 19,900 edges in total.

Then I thought that how many vertices can there be for 200 edges? I did the following $$\frac{n(n-1)}{2} = 200$$ Now, by simple algebra, I get a quadratic equation $$n^2-n-400=0$$By, solving the quadratic equation, I get $n=21, -20$ (Rounded off to the nearest whole numbers).
As the number of edges cannot be negative so, the number of edges can be 21 that can incorporate 200 edges. The total edges given are 200 and 200 - 21 = 179.

From, Intuition it can be derived that there can exist a subset of 67 out of the 179 unconnected edges, where no two edges are connected. Is it right?

Is there a better way to prove this or is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: You argue that for a suitable graph with the given properties, there *can* be a 67-vertex subset as desired. The problem asks whether *every* graph with the given properties *must* have such a 67-vertex subset.

Comment: Hint: try show that in general, for any graph $G$, $$\alpha(G) \geq \sum_{v \in V(G)} \frac{1}{1 + \deg(v)},$$ where $\alpha(G)$ is the cardinality of the maximum independent set. Using AM-HM inequality, we get, $$\alpha(G) \geq \frac{n^2}{2m+n}.$$

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on how did you use the AM-HM inequality. I see if I input n=200 and m=200, I get ~67 from $\alpha(G)>=\frac{n^2}{2m+n}$. But it would be helpful if you lay out a step by step process that proves the conditions in the question. I'll be very grateful.

Comment: The AM-HM inequality states if $x_i > 0$, then,
$$
 \frac{n}{1/x_1 + 1/x_2 + \cdots +1/x_n} \leq \frac{x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n}{n}.
$$
This gives,
$$
 \frac{1}{1/x_1 + 1/x_2 + \cdots +1/x_n} \leq \frac{x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n}{n^2}.
$$
And,
$$
1/x_1 + 1/x_2 + \cdots +1/x_n \geq \frac{n^2}{x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n}.
$$
Hence,
$$
\alpha(G) \geq \sum_{v \in V(G)} \frac{1}{1+\deg(v)} \geq \frac{n^2}{\sum_{v \in V(G)} 1+\deg(v)} \geq \frac{n^2}{n + 2m},
$$

Comment: Again, the hard part of the question should be proving $\alpha(G) \geq \sum_{v \in V(G)}$ in the first place. I'd encourage you not to google it.